# Unable to access the spring boot rest service from the WL server

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic

I am very new to spring boot stuff. My question is about how to access a spring boot rest service deployed on weblogc server. I have successfully deployed (at least it seems from the WL console) the spring boot war file to the weblogic 12c container. But I am not able to access the service.

I am trying to use the following url to access:
http://host:port/myweb/resource/hello -- I am also not sure whether I should use WL server port on which the war is deployed or 8080 (default spring-boot port)

I have given all the code below. Am i missing anything? I would greatly appreciate any help

## POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBootWL1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SpringBootWL1</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.example.demo.SpringBootWl1Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

### Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public class ResourceController {

@GetMapping("/hello")
String home() {
    return "Hello World, How are you!";
}
```

### Spring Boot Application

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootWl1Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWl1Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override 
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) { 
            return builder.sources(SpringBootWl1Application.class); 
    } 

}
```

### Weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:context-root>/myweb</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <!-- <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes> -->
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
```

### dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

Comment: WebLogic Server uses default port 7001, not 8080. You can check this in the config.xml file, in the config directory under your domain directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems ok. The default port of Weblogic is 7001, and every web application is deployed using this port.

To verify the deployment you can access to the console from (http://host:7001/console) and go to the **Deployments** section, there you must find your application deployed and it must be in **State OK**. Your can check there your web application context there.

One thing I noticed is your file is called: Weblogic.xml, but it must be called **weblogic.xml** all lower case.

Let me know if it is not working.